# OpenCV Python build from source with CUDA missing components

Tags: python, opencv

I am building OpenCV 4.5.4 form source with CUDA and everything is working fine. I can import "cuda" from cv2 and compute faster threshold, resize and so on. The problem is that I can't get to "cudalegacy" in Python where the function labelComponents() should be. I tried to set different options while configuring in CMake but without a luck. Can somebody please tell what I'm missing?

I tried to use "cudalegacy" in Visual Studio with C++ and had no issues.

Comment: it's possible that the stuff in `cudalegacy` module lacks the annotations to generate Python bindings.

Comment: can you please briefly explain how to do bindings in VS? It seems to me that this is already done. Under "bindings/opencv_python3"  opencv_world is referenced and under opencv_world is "cudalegacy". Where else do I need to look? Thanks

Comment: you can't do anything about this. you'd need to read OpenCV's source code and know what to change. besides, it's called *legacy* for a reason. that code is deprecated and will not receive any maintenance. the other cuda modules are to be preferred.

Comment: you understand that your writing is contradictory? "you can't do anything" and then "you need to know what to change" which is exactly what I asked if you can explain. Also, I don't see anywhere else in the source code a function that would preform this task looking just by name, so deprecated or not, I am not sure if I can use anything else. Thank you for the time.

Comment: try forum.opencv.org and tag with `cuda`. there are some people who might know how to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.